# Running python web app from docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I have a docker image of a python django web application. 
This is part of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos

RUN rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

RUN yum -y update && yum -y install vim python-devel python-pip postgresql-devel mercurial openssl-devel

RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"

ADD my_app.tar.gz /usr/src/my_app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/my_app

RUN export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss; pip install --upgrade -r /usr/src/my_app/req.txt

CMD ["python", "/usr/src/mdm_mock/manage.py", "runserver" "127.0.0.1:8081"]
```

This is how i run the container:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 myname/myapp:1.0
```

I have several questions:


1) When i run my container i get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: [python,: command not found
```

why?


2) How can i configure the docker so that my web app will use my postgres db on my local machine (my local machine is the host of the docker container)

Comment: When you installed your requirements, how did python get installed? Is it on the path to where you're trying to run the python cmd?

Comment: Show full `Dockerfile`

Comment: Added full Dockerfile

Comment: any soluition? running into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the full path the python command:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/python", "/usr/src/my_app/manage.py", "runserver" "127.0.0.1:8081"]
```

## Example

Build and run the container:

```
$ docker build -t myapp .
$ docker run -it --rm myapp 
Python 2.7.5
```

### Dockefile

```
FROM centos

CMD ["/usr/bin/python", "--version"]
```

Comment: still the same error `/bin/sh: [/usr/bin/python,: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MrT. Added an example. Can't reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably it doesn't matter but what if to run it not with `CMD` but with `RUN`

`RUN python /home/docker/app/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8081`

And don't you need to have a 
`apt-get install python` line in your Docker file?